# Is there a way to limit the boundaries of a drag event to the size of the screen?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I'm making a weather application and on one of the pages, users can save cities to quickly look up the weather for that city. I also want them to be able to delete a city in the list by pressing and holding and then dragging it to the delete button on the bottom of the screen.

The problem is that the label for the city name is the width of the entire screen and when you press and hold a city, you automatically grab the center of this label. Because of this, when you press the city name to much to the left of the label, the name disappears outside of the screen.

I can think of 2 possible solutions; make the screen have some kind of boundaries so nothing can disappear or make the label the width of the text within. But I can't find any of these solutions online. Does someone know how to do this or maybe has another solution?

This is the code for the xaml file.

```
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="CitiesListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:City">
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListCityTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="16" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <DragGestureRecognizer DragStartingCommand="{Binding Path=DragStartingCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CitiesViewModel}}}" DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CitiesViewModel}}, Path=CityTapped}"        
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5,10,5,10">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <DropGestureRecognizer DropCommand="{Binding DropOverCommand}"/>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Image HeightRequest="40"
                           WidthRequest="40"
                           Source="trash_icon.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

And this is the code for the drag and drop commands

```
        public Command DragStartingCommand => new Command<City>((param) =>
        {
            var dur = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
            Vibration.Vibrate(dur);
            _dragCity = param;
        });

        public Command DropOverCommand => new Command(() =>
        {
            if (Cities.Contains(_dragCity))
            {
                Cities.Remove(_dragCity);
                removeCity(_dragCity);
            }
        });

        public async void removeCity(City city)
        {
            await DataStore.DeleteCityAsync(city.id);
        }

        private City _dragCity;
```

Here is also a link to a video maybe better understand what I am talking about.  [Video](https://vimeo.com/668951856)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `DragGestureRecognizer` for the `Label` instead of `StackLayout`. A simple example for your reference. The text of Label would on the point which you pressed.

Xaml:

```
 private async void OnDropGestureRecognizerDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    }

    private async void OnDropGestureRecognizerDrop(object sender, DropEventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Correct", "Congratulations!", "OK");
        //await DisplayAlert("Incorrect", "Better luck next time.", "OK");
    }
```

Code behind:

```
 <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Label Text="Answer the following question by dragging your answer to the Entry." />
        <Label Text="What's 2+2?" />
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.5*, 0.5*"
          Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Label Text="3"
               HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <DragGestureRecognizer />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Text="4"
               HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <DragGestureRecognizer />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
        <Entry Margin="0,20,0,0"
           Placeholder="Drag your answer here">
            <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
                <DropGestureRecognizer DragOver="OnDropGestureRecognizerDragOver"
                                   Drop="OnDropGestureRecognizerDrop" />
            </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
        </Entry>
    </StackLayout>
```